# Program closes instantly after converting it with py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe, tkinter-button

I have a python program with a tkinter interface (the interface has 3 buttons, one of them is an exit button) which works perfectly fine. After i convert the program with py2exe to an .exe it instantly closes after i run the exe file. When i delete the exit button, it works also fine, even as a .exe.

This is the Exit button I created:

button_exit = Button(window, text="Exit", command=sys.exit())

If anyone has a clue whats going on here i would be very grateful.

Comment: Pass `command=sys.exit` as parameter (you DO NOT have to call the function!). Let me know if it works!

Comment: The program is likely crashing.
My guess is you have a resource that the program is trying to load and can't find.
For example if you have a logo that you usually load in your main without absolute path and you try to execute the .exe in a folder where the logo is not the program will crash

Comment: @AchilleG this is incorrect! The OP said: "When i delete the exit button, it works also fine, even as a .exe."

Comment: oh yes sry didn't read it through

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Button's command executed immediately when I create the Button, and not when I click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-my-buttons-command-executed-immediately-when-i-create-the-button-and-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, change

```
button_exit = Button(window, text="Exit", command=sys.exit())
```

to

```
button_exit = Button(window, text="Exit", command=sys.exit)
```